# Specializing vs Specialized

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences, conjugation

Should I use `specializing` or `specialized`? Or better, what's the difference?

> Microsoft is a German software development company **specializing**
>   in software development tools for the engineering industry.

Or

> Microsoft is a German software development company **specialized** in
>   software development tools for the engineering industry.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I did many research among companies presentations without getting an idea of what's more correct.

Comment: There is no such thing as "an German anything", it is "a German". This only adds to the impression that you should be at English Language Learners and not here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjectives with -ed or -ing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298009/adjectives-with-ed-or-ing)

Comment: @David: You are right, I did many changes to make this sentence as generic as possible and after changing the country name I forgot to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The past tense form ***specialised*** is unlikely in OP's exact context, but this is really a matter of (effectively, *arbitrary*) established idiomatic usage *for that specific verb/context*. Consider...

> 1: *[X] is a company **focused** on [whatever they focus on].* ([2160 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is%20a%20company%20focused%20on%22) in Google Books)
>    2: *[X] is a company **focusing** on [their speciality].* ([586 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is%20a%20company%20focusing%20on%22))

I think it would be clutching at straws to suggest that somehow the tiny semantic difference between being ***focused on*** something, and ***specialising in*** it could justify either tense choice. And there doesn't seem to be any "grammatical" rationale for the preference.

---

(As a Brit, I checked *specialise* rather than *specialize*. But I'm sure changing my search strings to AmE spelling wouldn't affect the results ratio significantly. And forget about [***focussing***!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=ElvCWqT6LInQsAXQjq-oBg&q=%22is%20a%20company%20focussing%20on%22&oq=%22is%20a%20company%20focussing%20on%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...788191.788191.0.788898.1.1.0.0.0.0.185.185.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.sb3g5Sk_tPM))

Answer (score -1):

The *-ing* suffix is defined by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/) as:

> 2. *(from other nouns)*
>
> something used in, consisting of, involving, etc

While the *-ed* suffix is defined as:

> *suffix*
>
> forming the past tense of most English verbs

It is also worthwhile to note the definition of "is":

> *verb*
>
> (used with he, she, it, and with singular nouns) **a form of the present tense** (indicative mood) of be

Thus, based on the defintions listed above, the more grammatical sentence would be:

> Microsoft is an German software development company **specializing** in software development tools for the engineering industry.

Hope this is helpful!